# How to make a php form readonly after submission and editable on the same page clicking on edit?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

How to make a php form readonly after submit and editable on the same page once clicking on edit.

Comment: You can use this <input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly>

Comment: it wil make the field readonly by default but i want it to be readonly after submit

Comment: which way use to submit form: ajax or page reload

Comment: Can you share your codes and try?

Answer (score 5):

You can not make entire form read-only by .you need to make all form controls read-only.

For example:

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" readonly>
```

You can make it editable again by:

```
txtName.prop("readOnly", false);
```

Or:

```
txtName.removeAttr( "readonly" );
```

Comment: yes, it will be useful, but first to check form is submitted or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it readonly by adding readonly to the tag.

```
<input type="text"readonly>
```

You can use jquery to add "readonly" when they press submit and probably remove it when they press edit.

This is how to add the readonly attribute

```
$('#inputId').attr('readonly', true);
```

And this is how to remove it:

```
$('#inputId').attr('readonly', false);
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/a1s1x5oc/

Comment: $( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $('#inputId').attr('readyonly', true);
});

#target would be the submit button and #inputId would be the input.